# Understanding Django coming from R Shiny?

Tags: django, shiny

First of all, my apologies if this isn't the best place to ask this.
My question isn't looking for an opinion of which one is better, but rather understanding what is going on as I am completely lost.
I am familiar with R Shiny and its concept of reactivity, just writing a whole HTML page with the objects linked to functions all in one go. I am now trying to understand Django, but it has proven quite difficult for me throughout the tutorials.

**Background:** Deployed basic apps internally at company using Shiny - the apps use authentication, collect data, push/pull to AWS S3, one linked to SQL database as well. Use HTML, SCSS and Javascript with Shiny. Know python to do Machine learning with it, now I am wanting to translate one of my apps to Django.

In Shiny, I can literally use functions that will generate HTML and CSS once the app is running.
I can describe "make a div here, with a button inside it, when the user presses it, change the background color of the div, wait 5 seconds and go back to original color".

Shiny will then generate the HTML and use *reactivity* to check if the button is being pressed or not, the server-side will be counting seconds and the CSS will change accordingly (look, this isn't verbally exactly what happens but you get the gist of it).

But in Django, so far I don't understand anything.
I write an HTML file with a div with id = mydiv. Inside it I place a numeric input with id 'my input', then what?
What if I want the number inside to generate div boxes interactively?
The user inserts '10' and immediately 10 blue boxes appear below it dynamically? Then code that if there are minimum 4 boxes clicked, an overlay appears saying 'Congratulations!'?

I do not even know how to begin, where do you link IDs with a function in the server - is that even how it works?

If someone could please refer me to understand how *reactivity* works in Django (or the alternative for it), thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Shiny is an extremely high level package that abstracts away a lot of details about server-side languages, HTTP, sockets, HTML, CSS, Javascript. Django doesn't do that. Django is *only* the server-side receiver of HTTP, period. All the client-side interaction that's realised through Javascript, HTML and CSS must be coded by you.

Comment: I definitely need to do more research on that. At least now I know where to start, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Django's relationship with HTML is just to provide a templating language that can help inject data from python objects into the static html that is rendered. It doesn't do any other creation of hooks that a frontend library would do.

Otherwise it operates as a place to make api calls to that your front end can use to manipulate itself with.

tl;dr - django doesn't really do anything with front end, it just renders it and provides it data

Comment: Right, so you have to use another framework on top of it to be able to make your website dynamic?

Comment: @Adrarc - Yep, exactly

Comment: @says Referring to elsewhere: The problem about doing anything but flagging on a malicious post is, that it might be "silently" deleted by users, instead of being deleted the loud way, by a diamond, with appropriate sanctions on the account instead of only on the post. That is why a user asked you to ONLY flag.